# How can I get the equation of the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

So the problem is the following:

Given a vector equation of a line L = (1,1,1) + d(1,0,-1), where d is any real number. Find the equation of a plane that is perpendicular to the line.

I was trying to use the equation get from the equation of a line a normal vector to the plane which have the same direction, and then use the equation of a plane given by a point and a normal vector. But that seems not working, because when I put the result on geogebra I got something wrong.

What is the procedure to get the problem?

Comment: You need to specify a point in the plane. Is the point $(1,1,1)$ contained in the plane?

Comment: No. it doesnt have to. The problem just give the vector equation of a line

Comment: Then there are infinitely many solutions. Does your professor/teacher really intend to check every possible solution that might be submitted? That seems very unlikely...

Comment: Just pick $(1,1,1)$ for definiteness. Then choose an arbitrary point in the plane $(x,y,z)$. What condition must the direction $r=(x,y,z)-(1,1,1)$ satisfy in order to be perpendicular to the line?

Comment: The dot product of r and any vector of the line must be 0 right?

Comment: That will describe the plane passing through $(1,1,1)$ that is perpendicular to the line.

Comment: The vector that is parallel to the line is $(1,0,-1)$ so $x-z=0\implies P=\{(x,y,z): z = x\}$ works.